# Post data on database with ajax laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a counter in Ajax and I would like to save the value of the counter in a database so that the value of the counter continues to grow even when the user disconnects or refreshes the page. I use the laravel framework. how to do it, please?

Comment: This is a really vague question. In general, you should do some research before posting a question like this. Consider looking for a specific database you want to use that is compatible with your framework (for example, SQLite), and look at its docs/try it out.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Matheus Junges still understood my problem from what I see.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `csrf_token()` to somewhere on the blade view:

```html
<input type='hidden' name='_token' value='{{ csrf_token() }}' id="csrf">
```

Add this route to your `routes/web.php` file:

```php
Route::post('add-to-counter', 'YourController@add');
```

Your php script:

```php
public function add()
{
   // retrieve de counter value from the database:
    $i = DB::table(...)->select(...)->get();
    $i = ++$i;
    // and save it to the database  
    return response()->json([
         'data' => $i
    ]);  
}
```

Then, create a ajax request:

```js
let _token = $("#csrf").val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'add-to-counter',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        '_token': _token,
    }
    success: function(response){
        // What happens if the ajax request finishes successfully
        alert("The current counter value is: "+response.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have created an example `add` function. Replace it with your own.